# What does Gift Of Blood / blood lightning do?

Tags: loop-hero

As in the title, what does it do? I've seen lots of blog posts and forum threads asking this, but I don't see any definite answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

Patch 1.101 notes (from 25th June) say:

> Fixed the "Gift of Blood" trait, now it does something except visual effects and sounds.

So before that point it seems that it actually did literally nothing in terms of gameplay and now I think it does some amount of damage on proc. I still probably wouldn't bother with it tbh.